# Unexplained current perturbation with 3 PWM PMSM control

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, pmsm, synchronous-motor

I encountered some problem of current measurement using the DRV8323RH to drive a PMSM motor in 3xPWM mode.

I am running a test under the following conditions:

- 1 DRV8323RH gate driver configured in 3 PWM mode
- 3 PWM generation
  channels configured in center-aligned mode
- 3 ADCs channels
  synchronized on low-side MOSFETs active state.
- Three phase PMSM driven in open-loop at very low speed using phased PWM inputs.

With those conditions,  the equation Ia + Ib + Ic = 0 must be respected.

The problem that I am facing now, is that I get some perturbations on my motor phase currents. This is illustrated in the pictures bellow. Second picture in a zoom. Time unit is millisecond.

The perturbations are very repeatable over the cycles and are not random. At the bottom of the graph, I compute the sum of the three currents and we can remark that this is equal to 0 most of the time. This observation makes me think that those ripples are really happening on the motor but I can't understand why.

Also, I noticed that the faster the current variates, the bigger is the perturbation magnitude.

Please tell me if you have any idea of the cause of my problem.

[image: 3 phase currents]

[image: Zoom into phase currents]

Comment: They look like PWM artefacts. Are they causing you operational or functional problems?

Comment: @Andyaka I verified my PWM generation with external scope and it looks clean. Those ripples prevent me from using this current feedbacks to build closed-loop control and other strategies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are running the motor open-loop.  When in closed-loop mode, the amplitude and frequency of you sinusoidal drive will adjust to match the back-emf of the motor, and the current will also be sinusoidal.  The back-emf amplitude will be close to the amplitude of your drive voltage.

In your case, the amplitude of the back-emf of the motor is significantly lower than the drive voltage, so that the rotor accelerates too quickly, then decelerates, depending on its rotary position.  Acceleration requires an increase in torque (and increased phase current) and during deceleration current is reduced.  You can see that when decelerating, the current drops and when accelerating, it increases.

To run slowly, you would have to reduce the amplitude of the drive until it is close to the motor's back-emf.  Matching the amplitude and frequency is difficult in open-loop mode, because if you adjust and the amplitude is just a little too low, or the frequency is a little too high, the motor will stop.  If you close the loop, your problem should go away.  Presently, your motor is acting more like a stepper, and the shaft is not turning smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and explanations. I am currently trying to run the motor with a closed-loop instead. I will let you know if I manage to make it smooth and clean.